# Active Directory Membership Provider across multiple domains

Tags: wcf, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have a WCF authentication service that uses active directory membership provider and provides AD login function and we have this working for one domain A. There is another domain B which is behind the firewall and there is a one way trust relationship between domain A and B. Users from domain B can log onto the domain controller of domain A but not vice versa. The WCF service is on Domain A. I tried to authenticate users from domain B using the service and I received the unknown username or bad password error.

I am wondering if anyone know if the active directory membership provider works across multiple domain with one way trust relationship? I have tried changing the LDAP connection string to point to domain A's domain controller but specify the DC parameter to Domain B and set the connectionUser to DomainB\Username but I received the same error. If I have everything pointing to DomainA I receives the same error too. The domain controllers for A and B can see each other. Does anyone know a solution?

(We can't point the LDAP string to domain B as its behind firewalls)

Thanks in advance